# Is it safe to dispatch_async in dealloc?

Tags: objective-c

I'm having a random `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`, but I can't point out the source. However, I'm wondering if this might be it:

I have an audio_queue created like this:

```
_audio_queue = dispatch_queue_create("AudioQueue", nil);
```

which I use to create and access an object called `_audioPlayer`:

```
 dispatch_async(_audio_queue, ^{
     _audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];
 });
```

The audio player is owned by a `MovieView`:

```
@implementation MovieView
{
     AudioPlayer *_audioPlayer
}
```

Then, in the `dealloc` method of `MovieView`, I have:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    dispatch_async(_audio_queue, ^{
        [_audioPlayer destroy];
    });
}
```

Is this acceptable? I'm thinking that by the time the block is called, the `MovieView` would have already been deallocated, and when trying to access the `_audioPlayer`, it no longer exists. Is this the case?

My crash report only says:

```
MovieView.m line 0
__destroy_helper_block_
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in that spot to see if `_audioPlayer` still exists?

Comment: I cannot replicate the crash consistently. Currently if I put a breakpoint there, yes, the `_audioPlayer` still exists.

Comment: Do you have a line number where the bad access occurs?

Comment: The only info I have is: `MovieView.m line 0
__destroy_helper_block_`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your bug is in the ivar access. This is due to how ivars work in ObjC: the `-dealloc` above is equivalent to

```
- (void)dealloc
{
  dispatch_async(self->_audio_queue, ^{
    [self->_audioPlayer stopPlaying];
  });
}
```

This can break because you end up using `self` after it is dealloced.

The fix is something like

```
- (void)dealloc
{
  AVAudioPlayer * audioPlayer = _audioPlayer;
  dispatch_async(audio_queue, ^{
    [audioPlayer stopPlaying];
  });
}
```

(It is frequently not thread-safe to explicitly or implicitly (via ivars) reference `self` in a block. Sadly, I don't think there is a warning for this.)

Comment: Why is the local variable in your suggested fix not `__weak`?

Comment: It's not weak because then it might be deallocated before the block runs, and then the `audioPlayer` object will never receive the `stopPlaying` message.

Comment: @moby Why should it be weak? It is not about to be dealloced and it is (presumably) not a thread-unsafe-release object.

Answer (score -2):

If this is the cause, the you could use dispatch_sync

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    dispatch_sync(_audio_queue, ^{
        [_audioPlayer stopPlaying];
    });
}
```

I haven't tested this

Comment: This still implicitly passes the block and thus the reference to `self` to another thread. There is no guarantee that this is safe. The check for `if (weakAudioPlayer != nil)` is also redundant and would be unsafe if it was necessary.

Comment: I think the only variable captured in the block is the weak variable.

Comment: Though I agree that the test for nil is redundant and can be removed, but it's not wrong either.

Comment: The example with `dispatch_sync()` passes the block to another thread, which likely causes `self` to be released on another thread, which might happen after `dealloc` returns. In theory it could ensure that the release happens on the thread calling `dispatch_sync()`, but I don't think this is guaranteed. The check against `nil` is wrong because weak variables can spontaneously become `nil` at any point.

Comment: But the execution of the dealloc-ing thread is stopped until dispatch_sync completes the block. I don't understand why you say self will be released on another thread.

Comment: The execution of the block itself will have completed, but there is no guarantee that the block is not retained and subsequently released in another thread. (As an optimization, the block might run on the *same* thread, but I don't think this is guaranteed either.)

Comment: Are you sure about this? Is there any piece in the documentation that mentions a block might be retained even after its execution? It sounds  strange to me.

Comment: In pseudocode, the other thread might do grab-and-retain-block-from-queue, execute-block, signal-completion-of-block-to-queue, release-block. The other thread could also decide to do `[[block retain] autorelease]` (as used to be conventional). In general, the assumption is that things are fine as long as retains/releases are "balanced"; there are very few guarantees as to when they happen, which is dangerous if another thread is involved.

Comment: I agree with you that using weak is wrong when you absolutely want the audio player to be destroyed on the same queue as it was created. Now that the initial post changed from `stopPlaying` to `destroy`, it's much obvious now. I edited my post to remove the second choice. I also posted a comment question to your solution

Comment: As part of the process for creating the block object, self will be retained because you are using an iVar inside the block.  This means that self will be retained after dealloc has been call on self... bad news any way you slice it.

Comment: There is another reason this answer is incorrect. The documentation for `dispatch_sync` states that `As an optimization, this function invokes the block on the current thread when possible.` I have tested this myself and what may end up happening is the block itself is executed on the calling thread (presumably the main thread), which renders using the GCD call in the first place moot.